# Binary Red Black Trees, adding a pointer?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to illustrate the algorithm for rotation on red-black trees.
How can I draw an external (and temporarly) pointer on the leaf '5'. 
The arrow should must come from above-left with a label ('y' for example).

My (uncomplete) example

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzstyle{arn_n} = [circle, white, font=\bfseries, draw=black, fill=black, align=center, inner sep=0pt,text width=1.5em, text centered]% black node
\tikzstyle{arn_r} = [circle, red, draw=red, align=center, inner sep=0pt,text width=1.5em, text centered, very thick]% red node
\tikzstyle{arn_x} = [rectangle, draw=black, align=center, inner sep=0pt,minimum width=0.5em, minimum height=0.5em]% NIL 'node'

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 5cm/#1, level distance = 1.5cm}] 
\node [arn_n] {33}
    child{ node [arn_r] {15} 
        child{ node [arn_n] {10} 
            child{ node [arn_r] {5} 
                   edge from parent node[above left] {$x$}} % name of pointer
            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
        }
        child{ node [arn_n] {20}
            child{ node [arn_r] {18}}
            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
        }                            
    }
    child{ node [arn_r] {47}
        child{ node [arn_n] {38} 
            child{ node [arn_r] {36}}
            child{ node [arn_r] {39}}
        }
        child{ node [arn_n] {51}
            child{ node [arn_r] {49}}
            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
        }
    }
; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A tip: instead of using the `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags, it's preferable to select the code and hit Ctrl-K or click the `{}` button; in this way you get colorized TeX syntax.

Comment: what do you mean with few more lines ? Wich information more ?

Comment: @madit: It's generally preferred to post a compilable example document that can be compiled as it is. Otherwise, people who want to try to help first of have to do the work of completing the document.

Comment: @Jake : done ;-) I do not find how to add an immage of the result.

Comment: @madit: See [how can i upload an image to be included in a question or answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2136)

Answer (score 5):

You can `name` the required node to make it available in a `\draw` command, and then use something like

```
\draw [<-, ultra thick] (leaf 5) -- node [auto] {$y$} ++(135:1cm) ;
```

to add the arrow with the label:

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzstyle{arn_n} = [circle, white, font=\bfseries, draw=black, fill=black, align=center, inner sep=0pt,text width=1.5em, text centered]% black node
\tikzstyle{arn_r} = [circle, red, draw=red, align=center, inner sep=0pt,text width=1.5em, text centered, very thick]% red node
\tikzstyle{arn_x} = [rectangle, draw=black, align=center, inner sep=0pt,minimum width=0.5em, minimum height=0.5em]% NIL 'node'

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 5cm/#1, level distance = 1.5cm}] 
\node [arn_n] {33}
    child{ node [arn_r] {15} 
        child{ node [arn_n] {10} 
            child{ node [arn_r, name=leaf 5] {5} 
                   edge from parent node[above left] {$x$}} % name of pointer
            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
        }
        child{ node [arn_n] {20}
            child{ node [arn_r] {18}}
            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
        }                            
    }
    child{ node [arn_r] {47}
        child{ node [arn_n] {38} 
            child{ node [arn_r] {36}}
            child{ node [arn_r] {39}}
        }
        child{ node [arn_n] {51}
            child{ node [arn_r] {49}}
            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
        }
    }
; 

\draw [<-, ultra thick] (leaf 5) -- node [auto] {$y$} ++(135:1cm) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A VERY THANKS to you. 
But what mean the value '135' ?

Comment: @madit: That's the angle of the line. You can specify points either in cartesian coordinates (`x,y`) or in polar coordinates (`angle:distance`).

Comment: hum ... i have a little problem. I have the same code but not the same result. On your image I see that the arrows doens't start from 'south' to 'north' but are well drawn on angle ! Not on my result :-( Something to configure in the preamble ? A conflict with an another package ?

Comment: @madit: Did you copy and paste the document from my answer? Then you should get the same result. What version of PGF are you using?

Comment: well, in the minimal document ... no problem with the lines ! in the syllabus that I wrote, the result is very different. This is probably due to a conflict with another package or another tikz library. Which will be difficult to find!

Comment: @madit: Hm, that's difficult indeed. Could you edit your question to include the output you get? Maybe we can figure it out just from the symptoms.

Comment: hum, like a newbies, i don't find how to insert an image in a comment (exept with an external URL, but i have'nt any repository)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5956/discussion-between-jake-and-madit)